# How can I use a different version of a package from the one required by a dependency?

Tags: java, osgi, jira-plugin

I’m trying to build an OSGI bundle, and I’m running into the following problem:

Let’s call my plugin “P”. Now, P has a dependency on another plugin “D”; it needs to use some interfaces exported by it. At the same time, I want to use version 2 of library “L” in plugin P. However, D also uses L, except it depends on version 1 of the library. Version 1 is provided by the container.

The thing is, none of the classes and interfaces of L appear anywhere in the API of D (at least none of those I’m using). That is, P and D each use classes from L internally, but they never exchange them.

So, as far as I can tell, it should be perfectly safe for each of them to use different versions of L, as long as I provide my own copy of Lv2. However, I can not for the life of me figure out how to make it work.

Here’s what I have: P’s pom.xml has a “provided” dependency on D, and a “compile” dependency L. I don’t have the sources for D, but OSGI tells me that it has an Import-Package for L;version=[1,2).

No combination of bundle instructions I tried could manage to make this work. Whatever I do, either D gets v2 of L, which leads to a “Constraint violation” BundleException blamed on D, or P’s classes get the v1 of L, which leads to a NoClassDefFoundError when running my code. (BTW, the missing class is not explicitly used by my code, it’s just used as a static member by another class in a different package of L.)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The canonical answer is to [build your plugin as an OBR](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Bundling+extra+dependencies+in+an+OBR). This means that you'll have to separate D into its own buildable plugin first with its own `pom.xml` and `atlassian-plugin.xm`l (let's call this new plugin "DP"). Within DP, you need to create a `<component>` (with [`public=true`](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Component+Plugin+Module)) to export any services that need to be used by plugin P, and then add `<component-import>` in P to get at them.

Since you don't have the sources for D, you will end up including D as a .JAR within DP. You may need to also write a simple shim on top of it. (Public components need to specify an interface in the `<component>` definition, which means that you will probably need to write one if the services you want to access in D are only classes and not interfaces.)

In this scenario, both P and DP get to list their own proper set of imports and they can specify whichever versions of the library they need.

Comment: I’m not sure if I misunderstand your answer or if you misunderstood my question, but that doesn’t sound right. D is *already* an OSGI plugin, and it has public components I import via component-import. I’m not trying to bundle D, I’m just importing packages from it. I’m trying to bundle *L*, and as far as I can tell I can’t, because D imports a different version of L.

Comment: For clarity, P is my plugin, D is Greenhopper, L is Guava, and the OSGI context is JIRA. JIRA itself provides Guava v11 (or 10, depending on version), which Greenhopper imports (with a [10,11] version bound). I’m trying to use Guava v18. It doesn’t work, even though no Guava objects are exchanged through the interfaces between my plugin and Greenhopper.

Comment: @bogdanb Is L a plugin in its own right as well? I understand that you are just trying to bundle L, but in the original description, it sounds like D is doing an OSGi import of L, which implies that maybe it is?

Comment: I see that our comments crossed in midair. Thanks for the clarification. I'll see if I can look at this the next time I'm back at my desk, since I know that I've previously bundled Guava in a similar context.

Comment: @bogdanb, you mentioned that GH gets a BundleException when you include Guava v18 with your plugin. When do you see this in the logs? Services should only get matched up for GH at bundle activation time, which means that I'd only expect to see this at system startup or when en/disabling GH itself, not your plugin. Could you be accidentally bundling GH in your plugin? Check your JAR to make sure. (If you built even once without `<scope>provided</scope>` in your GH dependency, even if you add it later, GH will still get included until you nuke `target/classes`.)

Comment: @bogdanb, if that's not it, can you post all of your `<component-import>`s and OSGi bundle instructions from your `pom.xml` and `atlassian-plugin.xml`? Do you have any `<component>` declarations with `public=true`? If so, please post those too.